# Changing the order of elements in stacked barchart by filter with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked, stacked-bar-chart

I would need some help with a Likert-scala bar chart that I created using ggplot2. Here is the data frame:

```r
structure(list(Q4_ROLE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), levels = c("Civilian Analyst", "Military Analyst", "Operations/Admin Specialist"
), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), levels = c("2021", "2022"), class = "factor"), Q20_A8 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    n = c(1L, 4L, 12L, 25L, 17L, 7L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
    4L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), perc = c(1.69491525423729, 
    6.77966101694915, 20.3389830508475, 42.3728813559322, 28.8135593220339, 
    11.2903225806452, 25.8064516129032, 25.8064516129032, 25.8064516129032, 
    11.2903225806452, 6.66666666666667, 13.3333333333333, 26.6666666666667, 
    53.3333333333333, 29.4117647058824, 47.0588235294118, 5.88235294117647, 
    11.7647058823529, 5.88235294117647, 50, 33.3333333333333, 
    16.6666666666667, 100), percent_answers = c(-0.0169491525423729, 
    -0.0677966101694915, 0.203389830508475, 0.423728813559322, 
    0.288135593220339, -0.112903225806452, -0.258064516129032, 
    0.258064516129032, 0.258064516129032, 0.112903225806452, 
    -0.0666666666666667, 0.133333333333333, 0.266666666666667, 
    0.533333333333333, -0.294117647058824, -0.470588235294118, 
    0.0588235294117647, 0.117647058823529, 0.0588235294117647, 
    0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 1), percent_answers_label = c("-2%", 
    "-7%", "20%", "42%", "29%", "-11%", "-26%", "26%", "26%", 
    "11%", "-7%", "13%", "27%", "53%", "-29%", "-47%", "6%", 
    "12%", "6%", "50%", "33%", "17%", "100%")), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I have five levels and I want them to be ordered correctly, but since I have it divergent I would need two different orderings. Using:

position_stack(reverse = TRUE)

works just fine when the plot was not divergent. I basically need the Neutral-Agree-Strong Agree to be reverse = TRUE and Strong disagree-Disagree to be reverse = FALSE so everything is in the right order on the divergent scale.

I have tried to filter with geom_col() to make 3-5 in a different direction than 1-2 but the second command overwrites my first one, making the filtering useless.

Q20_A8 is the Answer variable:

```
Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4","5"
```

```
count_8 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = percent_answers, fill = Q20_A8)) +
          geom_col(count_8 = filter(count_8, Q20_A8 %in% c("3","4","5")), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE )) +
          geom_col(count_8 = filter(count_8, Q20_A8 %in% c("1","2")), aes( y = percent_answers), position = position_stack(reverse = FALSE )) +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent_answers_label), size = 2.4,
            position = position_stack(reverse = FALSE, vjust = 0.5),
            color = "black",
            fontface = "bold") +
  facet_wrap(~ Q4_ROLE, nrow=3) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=8),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.3, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = +3),
        legend.position="bottom") +
    scale_fill_manual(name="Response:",
      values=c("#C0392B","#F5B7B1","#E5E7E9", "#85C1E9", "#2874A6"),
  labels=c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neither Agree/Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  ggtitle("Test") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5,1), labels = ylabs)
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

[image: Likert chart]

Comment: It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). If your data is proprietary, create a similar dataset that isn't. It's the structure and how the data is presented that is relevant. --in the meantime, have you looked at the `likert` package?

Comment: Thank you, I will edit the post with a reproducible data frame. Yes I checked that but I would love to do it with ggplot for now as everything is in place other than the stack order

Answer (score 0):

You should define `breaks` in your `scale_fill_manual` according to the specific order and define the order of your data frame in specific column using for example `fct_relevel` from `scales` package. Also you can use only `geom_bar(position="stack", stat = 'identity")` instead of two calls of bars. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
count_8 %>%
  group_by(Q4_ROLE, Year) %>%
  mutate(Q20_A8 = fct_relevel(Q20_A8,"1","2","3","4","5")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = percent_answers, fill = Q20_A8)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent_answers_label), size = 2.4,
            position = position_stack(reverse = FALSE, vjust = 0.5),
            color = "black",
            fontface = "bold") +
  facet_wrap(~ Q4_ROLE, nrow=3) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=8),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.3, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = +3),
        legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Response:",
                    values=c("#C0392B","#F5B7B1","#E5E7E9", "#85C1E9", "#2874A6"),
                    breaks = c("1", "2", "5", "4", "3"),
                    labels=c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neither Agree/Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  ggtitle("Test")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>